# infoPlist.strings Read Failed: The Data Couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

Tags: ios, swift, info-plist

I'm using xcode 7.3 and this error comes up after xcode crashes during import of .xliff file for localization....I think the crash is an xcode bug but not sure about the error.

I haven't found much information on this exact error.  I've checked the infoPlist.strings and it's the same as it's always been: IDELocalizationWork Temporary File

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: I would start by validating the xliff file against the applicable schema (either http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/xliff-core-1.2-strict.xsd or http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/cs02/xliff-core-1.2-transitional.xsd), just to make sure that it did not get broken during translation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is failing because the .xliff import has failed and blown away your infoPlist.strings file - replacing it with that placeholder text.

The placeholder text is not valid as a infoPlist.strings file.

So I don't believe that the infoPlist.strings is "the same as it's always been"